# header not appearing with classicthesis/arsclassica

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis

Good morning,
I'm writing my master thesis using the template of classicthesis with arsclassica. I would like to have in the header the chapter/section name and the page number but I don't find a way to make it appear up there. this is my preamble

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,%
           headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
           numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,%
           ]{scrreprt}  

\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}  
\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage{varioref}  
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,square,natbib]{biblatex}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,linedheaders,subfig,beramono,%
eulermath,pdfspacing,listings]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\input{arsclassica-settings}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=4.5cm,%
        heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{epstopdf}                       % Pakke der konverterer EPS til PDF
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[right]{showlabels}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

Can you tell my where I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 3):

By default `scrreprt` doesn't have headings.

Add the line

```
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

just before

```
\begin{document}
```

and you'll have them.

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,%
           headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
           numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,%
           ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,square,natbib]{biblatex}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,linedheaders,subfig,beramono,%
eulermath,pdfspacing,listings]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

%\input{arsclassica-settings}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=4.5cm,%
        heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{epstopdf}                       % Pakke der konverterer EPS til PDF
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[right]{showlabels}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]